# COPY failed: forbidden path outside the build context docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

THis is the project structure

```
Project
 /deployment
   /Dockerfile
   /docker-compose.yml
 /services
   /ui
     /widget
```

Here is the docker file

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

USER root

# create new user (only root can do this) and assign owenership to newly created user
RUN echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): ======> Setup Appusr" \
    && groupadd -g 1001 appusr \
    && useradd -r -u 1001 -g appusr appusr \
    && mkdir /home/appusr/ \
    && chown -R appusr:appusr /home/appusr/\
    && chown -R appusr:appusr /app

# switch to new created user so that appuser will be responsible for all files and has access
USER appusr:appusr

COPY ../services/ui/widget/ /app/
COPY ../.env /app/

# installing deps
RUN npm install
```

and docker-compose

version: "3.4"

```
x-env: &env
  HOST: 127.0.0.1

services:
  widget:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    command:
      npm start
    environment:
      <<: *env
    restart: always
```

and from `project/deplyment/docker-compose up` it shows

```
Step 6/8 : COPY ../services/ui/widget/ /app/
ERROR: Service 'widget' failed to build : COPY failed: forbidden path outside the build context: ../services/ui/widget/ ()
```

am i setting the wrong context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot `COPY` or `ADD` files outside the current path where `Dockerfile` exists.

You should either move these two directories to where `Dockerfile` is and then change your `Dockerfile` to:

```
COPY ./services/ui/widget/ /app/
COPY ./.env /app/
```

Or use `volumes` in `docker-compose`, and remove the two `COPY` lines.

So, your `docker-compose` should look like this:

```
x-env: &env
  HOST: 127.0.0.1

services:
  widget:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    command:
      npm start
    environment:
      <<: *env
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /absolute/path/to/services/ui/widget/:/app/
      - /absolute/path/to/.env/:/app/
```

And this should be your `Dockerfile if you use` volumes`in`docker-compose`:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

USER root

# create new user (only root can do this) and assign owenership to newly created user
RUN echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): ======> Setup Appusr" \
    && groupadd -g 1001 appusr \
    && useradd -r -u 1001 -g appusr appusr \
    && mkdir /home/appusr/ \
    && chown -R appusr:appusr /home/appusr/\
    && chown -R appusr:appusr /app

# switch to new created user so that appuser will be responsible for all files and has access
USER appusr:appusr

# installing deps
RUN npm install
```

Comment: RUN npm install  doesn't work for me

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'

I guess, it's because a volume is available after the container is built.

Comment: Then add `COPY . /app` before `WORKDIR /app` in your `Dockerfile` to make sure files are copied

Comment: I gave this answer a go but I am getting `ERROR: Duplicate mount points:`. This is what I have 
    volumes:
      - ./build:/usr/src/app/
      - ./api/database_changes:/usr/src/app/

Comment: @J.Do, you cannot have two same mount points (in your case `/usr/src/app/`. You should change one of them to another path.

Answer (score 10):

You problem is that you are referencing a file which is outside Dockerfile context. By default, is the location from where you execute the build command.

From docker documentation - [Copy section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

However, you can use the parameter -f to specify the dockerfile independently of the folder you are running your build. So you could use the next line executing it from projects:

```
docker build -f ./deployment/Dockerfile .
```

You will need to modify your copy lines as well to point at the right location.

```
COPY ./services/ui/widget/ /app/
COPY ./.env /app/
```